# Connect to XMPP server using SASL ANONYMOUS in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmpp, sasl

I want to connect to an XMPP server using SASL ANONYMOUS.

I can use any library that is available for commercial use.

Any advice on how to do this and what library to use?

I've looked into the documentation of some libraries (agsXMPP and jabber.net) and couldn't figure out how to do any anonymous connection on either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the OnSaslStart event you can select the Sasl anonymous mechanism

```
private void XmppCon_OnSaslStart(object sender, SaslEventArgs args)
{
   args.Auto = false;
   Mechanism.GetMechanismName(MechanismType.ANONYMOUS);
}
```